# Why adding null in HashSet does not throw Exception,but adding null in TreeSet throw Exception

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

Why adding `null` in `HashSet` does not throw `Exception`,but adding `null` in `TreeSet` throw Exception.

```
Set<String>  s = new TreeSet<String>();
        s.add(null);
```

throws `NullPointerException`

```
Set<String>  s = new HashSet<String>();
```

Allow `Null` value to be added.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the underlying data structure of a TreeSet is a [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which is a binary search tree and thus is sorted. For it to be sorted there must be a Comparator that determines whether a value is equal, lower or greater than another value. The default Comparator is not null-safe, if you'd however write your own Comparator that has support for null it would be no problem to use null as a key.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, that is how it has been implemented. According to the Java specification for [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html),

> This class permits the null element

And according to the javadoc for [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) in the [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) method it throws:

> NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements